# Moving a response into table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a response given below, I need to move program details into an array and show them in table. But I am getting undefined message since, programdetails is again an array.my programdetails is stored in `newprogramdetails[]`
if I give ng-repeat it gives duplicate error.

```
HTML:

   <tr ng-repeat="item in newProgramDetails">
    <td>{{newProgramDetails.title}}</td>
    <td>{{newProgramDetails.description}}</td>
    <td>{{newProgramDetails.createddate}}</td>
    <td>{{newProgramDetails.updateddate}}</td>

    </select></td>
  </tr>
```

JS:

```
UserService.getProgram(json).then(function(response) {

     $scope.newprograms = response.json.response.data;


                    for(var i=0;i<$scope.newprograms.length;i++){
                    newProgramDetails.push($scope.newprograms[i].programdetails);



                    }
                });
```

JSON:

```
{
  "json": {
    "response": {
      "servicetype": "4",
      "functiontype": "4004",
      "statuscode": "0",
      "statusmessage": "Success",
      "data": [
        {
          "programdetails": {
            "id": 256,
            "createddate": "2016-10-07 10:20:48",
            "defaultprogram": true,
            "description": "This is default program .",
            "ppin": "000256",
            "apin": "000256",
            "owner": true,
            "allowscheduling": false,
            "points": 0,
            "title": "Cakey Bakes Customer default program",
            "updateddate": "2016-10-07 10:20:48",
            "programtype": "Customer"
          }
        },
        {
          "programdetails": {
            "id": 257,
            "createddate": "2016-10-07 10:20:48",
            "defaultprogram": true,
            "description": "This is default program .",
            "ppin": "000257",
            "apin": "000257",
            "owner": true,
            "allowscheduling": false,
            "points": 0,
            "title": "Cakey Bakes Vendor default program",
            "updateddate": "2016-10-07 10:20:48",
            "programtype": "Vendor"
          },
          "userlist": [
            {
              "businessuserid": 44,
              "businessusername": "rk business New",
              "businessusermobile": "00",
              "businessusercountrycode": "91",
              "admin": true,
              "mobilevalidated": false,
              "emailvalidated": false,
              "email": "riteshnew@gmail.com",
              "upin": "000044"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need for loop for this.

Correct approach to solve your issue is:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in json.response.data">
    <td>{{item.programdetails.title}}</td>
    <td>{{item.programdetails.description}}</td>
    <td>{{item.programdetails.createddate}}</td>
    <td>{{item.programdetails.updateddate}}</td>

    </select></td>
  </tr>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/6t3b9mzy/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You have run-time syntax error at there,

```
HTML:

<tr ng-repeat="item in newProgramDetails">
    <td>{{item .title}}</td>
    <td>{{item .description}}</td>
    <td>{{item .createddate}}</td>
    <td>{{item .updateddate}}</td>    
  </tr>
```

Comment: What about duplicates ??

Comment: @NicoletaWilskon : newprogramdetails[] array having a details of every programdetails right?, then it will represent all array in a form of table row.