# How to map json arrays in angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, json

I am having problem in mapping json array in angularjs, can someone please look how can i correctly map the arrays and iterate their values. In arrays icdCode requires to be dynamic field (this is the other part i need help on) how can i achieve this correctly. thanks

**Way i am mapping in Controller**

```
  $scope.preAuthorizationInfo.collections.preAuthClinicalDetailInfoFormVO.active = active;
```

**Json arrays**

```
 "preAuthDiagnosisVOs": [
              {
                "preauthDiagnosisId": 165,
                "diagnosisVO": {
                  "diagnosisId": 171,
                  "diagnosisCode": "Provisional",
                  "icdCode": {
                    "icdCodeId": 1,
                    "description": "Other intestinal Escherichia coli infections",
                    "icdCode": "Other intestinal Escherichia coli infections",
                    "icdCodeChapter": "Certain infectious and parasitic diseases",
                    "icdCodeCode": "A04.4"
                  },
                  "active": false
                },
                "active": true
              },
              {
                "preauthDiagnosisId": 166,
                "diagnosisVO": {
                  "diagnosisId": 172,
                  "diagnosisCode": "differential",
                  "icdCode": {
                    "icdCodeId": 2,
                    "description": "Other viral enteritis",
                    "icdCode": "Other viral enteritis",
                    "icdCodeChapter": "Certain infectious and parasitic diseases",
                    "icdCodeCode": "A08.3"
                  },
                  "active": false
                },
                "active": true
              }
            ]
          },
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. As I see, you have an array with two elements: preAuthDiagnosisVOs[0]` and `preAuthDiagnosisVOs[1]`. Each element has a (hierarchical) structure (with fields `preauthDiagnosisId,diagnosisVO,active`). Explain what you mean by **mapping**.

Comment: @Kam : Refer this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40042670/moving-a-response-into-table/40042746) , this question is having your answer init.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to iterate over this object , You can use nested loop

```
angular.forEach(your_object.preAuthDiagnosisVOs, function(value, key) {
    if (angular.isObject(value)) {
        angular.forEach(value, function(value1, key) {
            if (angular.isObject(value1)) {
                angular.forEach(value1, function(value2, key) {
                    if (angular.isObject(value2)) {
                        angular.forEach(value2, function(value3, key) {
                            console.log(key + " : " + value3);
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log(key + " : " + value2);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log(key + " : " + value1);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log(key + " : " + value);
    }
});
```

And if you want just that active value just use

`yourObject.preAuthDiagnosisVOs[0].active` or `yourObject.preAuthDiagnosisVOs[1].active`

Hope this helps you . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just validate your json format it has some syntactical  issue. I have corrected this.

```
{
    "preAuthDiagnosisVOs": [{
        "preauthDiagnosisId": 165,
        "diagnosisVO": {
            "diagnosisId": 171,
            "diagnosisCode": "Provisional",
            "icdCode": {
                "icdCodeId": 1,
                "description": "OtherintestinalEscherichiacoliinfections",
                "icdCode": "OtherintestinalEscherichiacoliinfections",
                "icdCodeChapter": "Certaininfectiousandparasiticdiseases",
                "icdCodeCode": "A04.4"
            },
            "active": false
        },
        "active": true
    }, {
        "preauthDiagnosisId": 166,
        "diagnosisVO": {
            "diagnosisId": 172,
            "diagnosisCode": "Provisional",
            "icdCode": {
                "icdCodeId": 2,
                "description": "Otherviralenteritis",
                "icdCode": "Otherviralenteritis",
                "icdCodeChapter": "Certaininfectiousandparasiticdiseases",
                "icdCodeCode": "A08.3"
            },
            "active": false
        },
        "active": true
    }]
}
```

Now to access **active** key . **preAuthDiagnosisVOs** is array to access this you have to iterate with angular **forEach** loop. For access **active** key of each index just iterate and get it or to get directly use `object.preAuthDiagnosisVOs[0].active and object.preAuthDiagnosisVOs[1].active`.

I think it might be help you. Thank you